# How to use Jquery to toggle a class after a date-time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetime

How to use Jquery to toggle a class after a date-time?

I've not been successful with this at all. Looking for any help, I'm relatively green when it comes to code. Your help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please add the `javascript` tag to this question.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this [CodePen](http://codepen.io/krabbypattified/pen/MpEXjv).

It's just a matter of making 2 Unix timestamps in JavaScript and placing them in a `setTimeout` delay.

```
setTimeout(function() {
  // Do stuff here
  $(".block").toggleClass("red"); 
}, future - now);
```